# Solutions to the simplest equation for scalar fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

I am reading Matthew Schwartz's book on Quantum Field Theory. I have added images of the part I am having trouble understanding. I have just started out learning QFT, so apologies in advance if my questions are stupid.

How is equation (2.59) the most general solution to the equation 2.56? For, I can multiply $a^{\star}$ in 2.59 by any arbitrary number and the result will still be a solution to 2.56.

**Edit:** I think I have not made myself very clear. My question is: why is

${\int} \frac{dp^3}{(2 \pi)^3} (a_p(t)e^{i\vec{p}.\vec{x}}+2a^{\star}_p(t)e^{-i\vec{p}.\vec{x}})$

not a solution?

(I am assuming that $a^{\star}$ is the complex conjugate of $a$. Is this true?)

[image: Schwartz's book page 18]

[image: Schwartz's book page 19]

Comment: You can try to substitute it back into the equation to see if it is still a solution.

Comment: I think it does. I don't know if I am doing something silly, but I have checked and rechecked that it does. Since I am very new, I could be misinterpreting something.

Comment: Yes, in fact should be a solution since being $\phi$ just a linear combination of exponentials with coefficients $a$ and $a^\dagger$, if you rescale by a number it is still a linear combination of exponentials.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it is time to review some basic calculus first?

Comment: You could be right, but could you be a little more specific? Do you mean that multiplying $a^{\star}$ by a constant makes the expression not a solution to the differential equation, or that it does?

Comment: OP: this is the most general *form* of a solution. Any solution you can come up with has this form, with some function $a_p$. If you multiply it by a number you'll get a different function that will correspond to a different solution that would still have the same form.

Comment: The solution OP is suggesting does not satisfy the reality condition, i.e. $\phi(x)\neq\phi^*(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question as I understand it now.

The field $\phi(x,t)$ has to be purely real. This is not stated anywhere but is implied. This was all that was to my confusion.